# jQuery tablesorter change header on run-time

Tags: jquery, header, tablesorter

I've a question to jQuery tablesorter. Is there a way to change the headers-attribute on run-time?

On start I do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("table").tablesorter({debug:false, headers: {4:{sorter:false}}}); 
});
```

In my Script there's a link:

```
<a href="javascript: xxx()">xxx</a>
```

This is calling this function:

```
function xxx() {
    $("table").tablesorter({debug:false, headers: {3:{sorter: false}}}); 
}
```

The goal is to disable the third column, too. Do you habe any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To toggle the sorting of a column, you need to do two things:

- Toggle "sorter-false" class name on the header.
- Toggle the `sortDisabled` attribute on the header.

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/564/):

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue'
    });
    $('button').click(function(){
        var $th = $('th:contains(Sex)'),
            status = !$th[0].sortDisabled;
        $th.toggleClass('sorter-false', status );
        $th[0].sortDisabled = status;
    });
});
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you very much for the genius advice!